# Infinite scrolling for scrolling up a tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a chat messaging app where it loads my messages from earliest to latest, then auto scrolls to the bottom so the user sees the latest.

I'm only loading 25 messages, then when the user scrolls to the top, I'd like to upload the next 25 messages. It's proving to be really tricky and ending up in an infinite loop.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard indexPath.row == 1 else { return }
    fetchNextMessages(with: lastReference: lastMessage.reference)
}
```

Before the table finished scrolling to the bottom, it started fetching the next set which is wrong. So I tried this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 else { return }
    fetchNextMessages(with: lastReference: lastMessage.reference)
}
```

However, same issue. Any better way to handle this?

Comment: So you're trying to load more messages once they scroll to the top?  I would check contentOffset inside of scrollViewDidScroll..  Check contentOffset.y -- if it's greater than 10 or something then load your new messages and insert them at the top of your table view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that this method is being called multiple times , you should make `fetchingNow = false` after you reload the table with new data , besides when you load the new content don't make the scroll to the oldest ones and leave the user to scroll up to see remaining

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 else { return }

    if(!fetchingNow)
    {
        fetchNextMessages(with: lastReference: lastMessage.reference)
    }

}
```